# How to Set Vertical Separators for JMenuItems

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I can only set horizontal separator to my code , how to set vertical one ? Similar to this 
http://jade-cheng.com/hpu/2012-spring/csci-2912/assignment-5/blueprint-2.png

```
    file.add(newMenuItem);
    file.add(openMenuItem);
    file.add(saveMenuItem);
    file.add(subMenu);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(exitMenuItem);
```

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem? Also, a screenshot of what's happening and a mockup of what you want to happen might help as well.

Comment: And, could you whip up an ascii-art sketch of what you're trying to get? Why do you need a vertical separator in a menu?

Comment: A vertical separator would be used wen components are displayed horizontally. A horizontal separator is used when components are displayed vertically. This is how all applications that use menus work, like your Browser, Word, etc. Companies spend millions of dollars to have a consistent UI. Why are you trying to change this?

Comment: I cannot imaging a vertical separators in MenuItem... Could you give some example? Some screen with expected result you've seen elsewhere?

Comment: see vertical separator which contains icons guys http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/MenuitemseparatorSmartGWT.htm

Comment: see here as well http://jade-cheng.com/hpu/2012-spring/csci-2912/assignment-5/blueprint-2.png

Comment: That sort of design decision would be a matter for the look and feel, you just set the icon for the menu item and let the L&F take care of rendering it in a way that's consistent with other apps on the target platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical separator in JMenuItem? The only thing which comes to my mind and which you can treat as a JSeparator is something like below:

[image]

But this left "JSeparator" is not an extra added JSeparator, but depends on LookAndFeel.

Below you see the same JFrame with the same JMenuBar but with different lookandfeel:

[image]

The code for both screens is exactly the same, but executed with different look and feels:

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    public NewClass() throws HeadlessException {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Open..."));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Save"));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Save as..."));
        menu.addSeparator();
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Delete"));

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
           //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
           UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());      
           new NewClass();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

Note, that

```
menu.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL));
```

will not generate any separator at all (you can try)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @guitar_freak, some LayoutManagers give you this effect for free, whereas others do not.  If you wanted this effect for any LM, you'll have to roll up your sleeves a bit.

A `JMenu` is an `AbstractButton` that has no layout by default.  When you add something to a JMenu, you're actually adding it to the menu's internal `JPopupMenu`, which has a `DefaultMenuLayout` (subclass of `BoxLayout`) as it's layout by default.

Things to try: write your own `MenuItemUI` to install on the JMenu, or subclass the JMenu to use a JPopupMenu with a different LayoutManager.  I haven't tried either so I'm not sure which is correct.

Personally, I'd just leave it up to the L&F as @guitar_freak suggested. It seems to much work for too little gain, but ultimately, only you can decide that.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

file.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));